# Is it a must to learn html5/javascript for cross platform development?

Tags: html, cross-platform

Based on my research, most (if not all) frameworks use html5 and javascript when it comes to cross platform mobile development. Are there any that use good ol' java or some other language? I haven't gone deep into front-end development and design, that's why.

EDIT: Came across [this](https://uxmag.com/articles/native-or-web-based-selecting-the-right-approach-for-your-mobile-app), and it cleared up my misconceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If By cross-platform, you mean web-based apps? then you have to use html-javascript-css technology. (Phonegap, codova etc) but there is also  C#-based apps, like those built using the Xamarin platform.
But native app development has more performace advantage over cross-platform for obvious reasons. :)

Comment: web-based pointed me in the right direction, thanks dude :D

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot Frameworks to work for cross platform developments.
I would recommend Ionic UI Framework, it built on Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Xamarin Framework](https://xamarin.com/) for cross platform mobile development using C#, but it's free version very limited.

Comment: Xamarin has lots of gadgets, it's great and all, but like you said, free is limited :(